# Create a zipped tar archive of a full centos filesystem, and open in Windows

Tags: centos, tar

I'm trying to create a zipped tar archive of all files on a centos 7 machine. I'm using this command:

```
sudo tar -cvzp --exclude=backup --exclude=swapfile -f /backup/archive/full-backup-$today.tar.gz  --one-file-system /
```

When I do this, I can perfectly untar the file on centos with tar -xvf
However, the file is not readable in Windows (via winrar & winzip). I think it has something to do the way it was tarred.

Since I want to be able to recover some files in Windows, I would like to be able to open it in Windows.

THanks!

Comment: I would also exclude /dev, /sys, /srv, /proc. Though -p may already be disposing of many (all?) of them.

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/234649/how-to-extract-a-tar-file-tgz-in-windows

Comment: @AlienLifeForm Thanks for the tip!
@GeraldSchneider; I know how to extract a tar file. However, it's not working, so I believe it has something to do how I tar the files.

Comment: @AlienLifeForm `-p, --preserve-permissions` seems to be irrelevant. From `man tar`: extract  information  about  file permissions (default for superuser). You're probably right about excluding these directories though.

Comment: @yahol You are indeed correct - I misread -p as --one-file-system (only root knows why)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you could try 7zip - it works with .tar, .tar.gz files.
You can also `zip` and `unzip` files on Linux for better compatibility with Windows' zip.

Comment: Windows 1803 and later will [include `tar` out of the box](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/01/18/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/), so 7zip (or starting up WSL) will no longer be a requirement when handling *.tar* files.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to use 7zip, but also there I get a message that the archive is corrupt

Comment: @mitch2k can you extract dirs from top level one by one, to see which one is causing trouble? Can you also try `zip` instead of `tar` on Linux and then extract it on Windows?